# Ideas for designing the logo of a national logic association

Tags: logo

I am not a professional graphic designer but I am going to design a logo for "Iranian Association for Logic" which made an announcement for gathering ideas about designing it. My proposed design is shown below. It will be used in an official website and news bulletins, scientific journals, official documents and so on.

> **Question 1:** I would like to know if it is well-designed, creative and interesting enough for such an association in any sense which a professional designer defines? What are the possible strength and weaknesses of this logo? Are its symbols and fonts well-chosen and appropriate? What about its slogan, "Logic for all, all for logic"? Is it an old fashioned motto?
>
> **Question 2:** If anything is wrong with this logo, could you please give me an insight how to improve it?
>
> **Question 3:** My proposed logo is somehow classic, what is a "modern" logo idea for such an organization including its abbreviated name "IAL", "a logical symbol" (here the "universal quantifier (inverse A)") and probably an I[ranian national symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_symbols_of_Iran) (for example "[Damavand volcanic mountain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Damavand)")?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Government agencies tend to all suffer the same with their logos: trying to do too much and being too literal.

As such, most government agencies don't really have logos as much as they have 'official seals'. What makes a seal vs. a logo is open to interpretation, of course, but to me, a seal tends to be:

- overly detailed
- usually always in a circle format
- usually always has a border
- usually always have type that is too small

That said, sometimes a seal makes more sense. It's not stylish, but does feel rather 'official' and sometimes that's an important 'vibe' for your logo to have.

Some specific comments:

- It appears I, A, and L are all different typefaces. That could work, but right now, they aren't different enough to me. As it is, it just feels like an oversight. Maybe emphasize the differences more.
- The ornate border decoration feels out of place with the rest of the logo (however, I'm not familiar with Iranian culture and perhaps that makes a lot of sense in that context)

Comment: Have you any idea about its slogan? Should I choose a better one?

Comment: ouch... what is the background of the association, what is its history and purpose.

Comment: I just googled "Iranian Graphic Design' there is some really hot work out there, contemporary and influenced, no reason why you should compromise.